# How to add primary id referring to 2 unique columns, and 1 unique column in table (multiple joins)

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Client First Name   Client Last Name    Patient Name
John    Wick    Raffie
John    Wick    Coco
Rick    Thomas  Sussie
Peter   Parker  Hershey
Peter   Parker  Malt
Rick    Thomas  Poky
Lucas   Desmond Timmy
```

Result should be:

```
Client ID   Client First Name   Client Last Name    Patient Name    Patient ID
1   John    Wick    Raffie  1
1   John    Wick    Coco    2
2   Rick    Thomas  Sussie  3
3   Peter   Parker  Hershey 4
3   Peter   Parker  Malt    5
4   Rick    Thomas  Poky    6
5   Lucas   Desmond Timmy   7
```

[image: raw]

[image: result]

What I did is create a stored procedure to select the contents of the client table with `row_number()` then join it with patient table with `row_number()` also, but I want to know if I can do it in one t-sql script only?

Thank you.

Comment: Client table?  Patient table?  I don't understand.  What table is which?

Comment: client table contains client details (client firstname and last name) while patient table  (patient name)

Comment: Provide your sample data in the form of DLL and `INSERT` statements. Images and text mis-aligned data aren't helpful for other users. Here's a place to start: [Forum Etiquette: How to post data for a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)

Comment: @Larnu I also include a picture for my question. thank you.

Comment: Images are even worse than misaligned text.

Answer (score 0):

I think that **DENSE_RANK()** function can be helpful in your problem

```
Select      DENSE_RANK() OVER( order by t.[Client First], t.[Client Last Name]) as [Client ID]
        ,   t.[Client First]
        ,   t.[Client Last Name]
        ,   t.[Patient Name]
        ,   DENSE_RANK() OVER( order by t.[Patient Name]) as [Patient ID]    
From [Table] t;
```

Comment: Thanks Jacek will try this query. Life Saver!

Comment: THE ABOVE ANSWER IS ABSOLUTELY RIGHT BUT INSTEAD OF DENSE RANK IN PATIENTID GIVE RANK

Comment: @user9192401 why are you shouting?